# 9 by 9 matrix: finding the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can it be done analytically? I have a system I need to solve, but would need to take a determinant of a 9 by 9 matrix. Is it worth the effort, or is there a limit (in rank) above which it's not possible to solve determinants anymore?

Comment: Why would you calculate the determinant if you have to solve a linear system anyway?

Comment: There is not a limit. However it is **exceedingly tedious**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to compute the determinant as an alternating sum of products then you'll have $n!$ terms. Not nice for $n$ even moderately large. For instance, for $n=100$, it'll take longer than the universe exists.

Your best bet is to reduce the matrix to triangular form using row operations and compute the product of diagonal terms.

Comment: And this would solve the system without even computing any determinant. I'm always really surprised when I see that the only known method for solving a linear system is Cramer's rule.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that. It's so much easier!